# Why is Springboot's JPA entity abstract?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I inherited a Springboot based piece of software, in which each entity is represented by at least two data types. For example:

**The DTO:**

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyEntityDTO {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String description;
    String type;
    Long parentId;
    String parentSerialNumber;
}
```

**The corresponding JPA entity (table):**

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "my_entities_table")
@Entity

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public abstract class MyEntity extends IdBasedEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    Parent parent;
    @Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    String type;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String externalId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String myentityName;
    @Column
    String description;
}
```

My question is: What design principles and/or patterns does an **abstract** JPA entity satisfy?

I am trying to understand this because I was surprised to discover that I cannot mock this entity in a JUnit. I am assuming there is a good design reason for this.

Comment: This is opinion based, but no one can tell why some one did it. You'd have to see what extends MyEntity and where and how it is used - but it is the root of an inheritance graph of subentities, so they likely wanted to ensure no one tried creating instances of this in the database which would have no meaning to the application. You would want to use specific instances of the subclasses, not this parent/root class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To complete @Chris comment.**

According to JPA specification

> An entity may inherit from a superclass that provides persistent
> entity state and mapping information, but which is not itself an
> entity. Typically, the purpose of such a mapped superclass is to
> define state and mapping information that is common to multiple entity
> classes.